# Python : re-order dict of dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is my dict form:

```
{frame:{point:Vector}}
```

and i need to re-build/order it to get something like this:

```
{point:{frame:Vector}}
```

Here is an example of code:

```
{1: {'pt0': Vector((0.09608151018619537, 0.1202411875128746)),
     'pt1': Vector((0.3969220519065857, 0.2085522711277008)),
     'pt2': Vector((0.3969220519065857, 0.7914475202560425)),
     'pt3': Vector((0.09608148038387299, 0.8797586560249329))},
 2: {'pt0': Vector((0.09217172116041183, 0.1268879920244217)),
     'pt1': Vector((0.4093528687953949, 0.20748035609722137)),
     'pt2': Vector((0.4093528687953949, 0.7925194501876831)),
     'pt3': Vector((0.09217172116041183, 0.8731117844581604))}}
```

And here is what i need (vector value are not good, hand typing..):

```
{'pt0': {1: Vector((0.09608151018619537, 0.1202411875128746)),
         2: Vector((0.09217172116041183, 0.1268879920244217))},
 'pt1': {1: Vector((0.3969220519065857, 0.2085522711277008)),
         2: Vector((0.4093528687953949, 0.20748035609722137))},
 'pt2': {1: Vector((0.09608151018619537, 0.1202411875128746)),
         2: Vector((0.09217172116041183, 0.1268879920244217))},
 'pt3': {1: Vector((0.09608151018619537, 0.1202411875128746)),
         2: Vector((0.09217172116041183, 0.1268879920244217))}}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What have you tried? Or, if you haven't tried anything, what are you stuck on? Do you know how to iterate over the items of a dictionary? How to add items to a new dictionary? (As a hint, `collections.defaultdict` or the `setdefault` method can make this less verbose, but it can be written pretty easily even if you don't know either, by using the `in` operator or a `try`/`except`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think of the loops you'd do, in English terms:

For each frame, for each point, find the point in the new dict, then add the frame under that.

To translate that to Python, we need to add a couple details: create the new dict in advance, and create the sub-dict for the point if "find" didn't find it. But other than that, it's a trivial translation:

```
newdict = {}
for frame, pointsvectors in olddict.items():
    for point, vector in pointsvectors.items():
        if point not in newdict:
            newdict[point] = {}
        framesvectors = newdict[point]
        framesvectors[frame] = vector
```

You can obviously condense this by getting rid of some of the intermediate steps, and by using a `defaultdict` or the `setdefault` method instead of the `in` check, but I'll leave those as exercises for the reader.

As an even better improvement, if you need to do this more than once, you can generalize into a `swap_levels(olddict, level1=0, level2=1)` function that works on any multi-level dictionary, so you can just write this as:

```
newdict = swap_levels(olddict)
```